# Create a column using Pandas to check if sum of a column for one category is greater than the other category

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with the following format, the IDs are repeated where several of the same people are working on various projects in different departments.
I need to assign a 'New Department' based on the %oftimespent on a department.

For example:

**If Sum of %oftime spent is higher in D1 than In D2 for a specific ID, the new department will be D1.**

```
ID    %oftimespent  department
13782       25            D1
13782       75            D2
13162       25            D1
13162       45            D1
13162       30            D2
```

Resulting Dataframe:

```
ID    %oftimespent  department  newdepartment
13782       25            D1     D2
13782       75            D2     D2
13162       25            D1     D1
13162       45            D1     D1
13162       30            D2     D1
```

I am using Python Pandas to process all this. Any logic that could help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
Generate a new `df` in which you drop duplicated `IDs` after you sort `df` on `ID` and %`oftimespent`

s=df.sort_values(by=['ID','%oftimespent']).drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'],keep='last')
```

Create dict from new datframes' ID and %oftimespent columns and map over to the original df

```
df['newdepartment']=df['ID'].map(dict(zip(s.ID,df.department)))
print(df)




     ID  %oftimespent department newdepartment
0  13782            25         D1            D2
1  13782            75         D2            D2
2  13162            25         D1            D1
3  13162            45         D1            D1
4  13162            30         D2            D1
```

Answer (score 0):

Groupby `ID` and `department`, get the sum of `%timespent`, compare values and create a mapping:

```
mapping = (df.groupby(['ID','department'])['%oftimespent']
             .sum()
             .unstack()
             .assign(newdepartment = lambda df: np.where(df.D1.gt(df.D2),
                                                         'D1', 'D2')
                     )
           ['newdepartment']
           )
```

Map mapping to the original dataframe's ID column:

```
df.assign(newdepartment = df.ID.map(mapping))

      ID  %oftimespent department newdepartment
0  13782            25         D1            D2
1  13782            75         D2            D2
2  13162            25         D1            D1
3  13162            45         D1            D1
4  13162            30         D2            D1




ID
13162    D1
13782    D2
Name: newdepartment, dtype: object
```